# Cannot get wkhtmltopdf to work in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am trying to use wicked_pdf in my rails 3 application. I have followed all the tutorials and I am getting this error:

```
Failed to execute:
"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q        "file:////var/folders/_b/50kywsc97r95gvr9gy9nr6700000gn/T/wicked_pdf20130228-874-a51lgi.html" "/var/folders/_b/50kywsc97r95gvr9gy9nr6700000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20130228-874-1ihqg74.pdf"
```

I know that wkhtmltopdf exists in the right place because when I type which wkhtmltopdf I am shown the path above. I also get told it's there when I try to brew install again. Furthermore when I type wkhtmltopdf google.com google.pdf it runs fine.

My controller looks like this:

```
def show #shows some material
@material = Material.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => '#{@material.id}',
             :wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
    end
  end
```

end

Any suggestions? Does this seem like a wkhtmltopdf issue or a wicked_pdf issue? I have bundle installed everything and bundle updated everything. I have added the wkhtmltopdf-binary gem (which shouldn't be necessary). It doesn't work on heroku either.

Comment: you can set a flag to render the stuff as html, does this work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The idea is to render the stuff as a pdf; it already works as html. Or am I missing the point (quite possible)?

Comment: usually, you include extra infos in a pdf (pagenumber etc) with custom headers. you can set ```show_as_html``` as an option to see the output before it's piped into wkhtmltopdf. this is great to make sure that the rendering is actually working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like there may be a few wkhtmltopdf images out there. If rails is trying to use /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf, try the command /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf from a terminal and see is there are any problems running that one. If you have a few copies around from different gem installs, the one that runs first in your search path may not be the one rails is trying.

Hope it helps

Bob

Answer (score 1):

First validate the location of the binaries

1. Open a terminal prompt and type

   `$ which wkhtmltopdf`

The return in my machine is

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

1. Validate the binaries are working well

   `wkhtmltopdf google.com google` It must generate a pdf with the google webpage
2. Create a class in your initializer

[Look at my gist](https://gist.github.com/rderoldan1/5577714)

And that's all